# JPA CriteriaQuery Unable to locate appropriate constructor for sum of date diffrerence

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteriaquery

I know this question look similar, but I think for me the case is different

this is the exception message

> Exception while fetching data (/periodicReport/userReport) :
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate
> appropriate constructor on class
> [com.analytics.entity.projections.UserParticipantCountAndDurationImpl].
> Expected arguments are: java.util.UUID, long, java.util.Date [select
> new
> com.analytics.entity.projections.UserParticipantCountAndDurationImpl(generatedAlias0.userID,
> count(distinct generatedAlias0.userID), sum(function('TIMEDIFF',
> generatedAlias0.endTime, generatedAlias0.startTime))) from
> com.analytics.entity.ConferenceParticipant as
> generatedAlias0 group by generatedAlias0.userID order by :param0 desc]

I'm expecting the sum to be Long and I have specified it in the criteria query.
I don't have any idea where Date is defined

the snipet for the buider

```
Expression<Long> sum = criteriaBuilder.sum(
            criteriaBuilder.function(
                    "TIMEDIFF",
                    Long.class,
                    participantRoot.<Date>get("endTime"),
                    participantRoot.<Date>get("startTime")
            )
    );
    Expression<Long> count = criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(participantRoot.get("userID"));
    reportQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(
            UserParticipantCountAndDurationImpl.class,
            participantRoot.get("userID").as(UUID.class).alias(USER_ID),
            count.as(Long.class).alias(PARTICIPANTS),
            sum.as(Long.class).alias(PARTICIPANT_DURATION)
    ));
```

the class in question

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserParticipantCountAndDurationImpl implements UserParticipantCountAndDuration, Serializable {

   private UUID userID;

   private long participants;

   public long participantDuration;

   public UserParticipantCountAndDurationImpl(
           UUID userID,
           long participants,
           long participantDuration
   ) {
       this.userID = userID;
       this.participants = participants;
       this.participantDuration = participantDuration;
   }
}
```

And yes I have tried to change signature of the constructor. in that case the query will run, but then thows CastException since it java.util.Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIMEDIFF return date time as the result, so it cant be casted to Long or double, the the Sql object in the raw result is DateTime, [refer this](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php).
I can solve this by using a function to get minutes from the datetime. but I solved this by getting difference of UNIXTIMESTAMP for both the datetime for the summation. Since UNIXTTIMESTAMP is always *long* I can cast it to Long or BigInteger

Answer (score 0):

you need a Expression with the name of the unit you want to extract from the timediff function

```
public static class TimeUnitExpression extends BasicFunctionExpression<String> implements Serializable {

    public TimeUnitExpression(CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder, Class<String> javaType,
            String functionName) {
        super(criteriaBuilder, javaType, functionName);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(RenderingContext renderingContext) {
        return getFunctionName();
    }
}
```

so your sum expression becomes

```
    Expression<Long> sum = criteriaBuilder.sum(
            criteriaBuilder.function(
                    "TIMEDIFF",
                    Long.class,
                    new TimeUnitExpression(null, String.class, "MILLISECOND"),
                    participantRoot.<Date>get("endTime"),
                    participantRoot.<Date>get("startTime")
            )
    );
```

Comment: Sorry @tremendous7, ur talking about TIMESTAMDIFF function here, TIMEDIFF does not require any unit. I have figured out the issues anyway, thanks for the reply